# Hover with span and css3

Tags: html, css, hover, transition

I just created a hover for my menu, but I have a problem with the "span".

I cant't set the width for 100%, so that I will see the all text from the button. 
I know that it is possible to set the width rigidly but it should be inherit from the text width.

Can anyone help me with that?

Thanks.

jsfiddle.net/35ufuzw4/

Comment: Please put your code in the question. Placing a JSFiddle link in a code block to bypass the *JSFiddle links must be accompanied by code* warning is breaking the rules. I've taken the liberty to comment this code block out to allow you to fix it.

Comment: set `display:block` to `span`

Comment: Edited. Unfortunately the display:block has not helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've made this a bit more complex than it needs to be.  Here's an updated version of your fiddle:

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/35ufuzw4/2/)

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" class="navi">Home</a>
<a href="#" class="navi">About</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.navi {
    float: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
}
.navi:hover {
    color: #582d1d;
}
.navi:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    background-color: #000;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.05, 0.06, 0.05, 0.95);
    transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.05, 0.06, 0.05, 0.95);
}
.navi:hover:before {
    top: 0;   
}
```

**Here's how it works:**

Instead of using lots of extraneous markup, we keep things semantic using a pseudo element.  The `::before` pseudo element has position set to absolute, so when its top/left/right/bottom properties are all set to 0, it will be fill the space of the .navi element that has its position set to relative.  Setting its top position to 100%, means that we're going to move the top all the way to the bottom.  This allows you to set the top to 0 on hover and have the background-color appear to grow from the bottom up.

The `.navi` class itself is applied to an anchor tag, so since anchor tags are inline, we can float this element and give it some padding left and right.  Using line-height, you can control how tall the element is and ensure that the text inside it is vertically aligned in the center.  Add a hover pseudo class and you can change its color when the background 'grows' up behind it.